# What is the difference between typof and $.type()?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between typof and $.type() in respective of javascript or jquery ,When i tried  below

```
  $.type(new Boolean()); // return "boolean"   
   typeof(new Boolean()); // return "object"
```

Comment: Have a look [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). This is because you instantiate your Boolean with `new`, thus Javascript interpretes it as an object. `typeof(Boolean(true))` should return `boolean`

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` is a JavaScript operator which tells you whether something is a primitive, and if so which kind of primitive, or an object. If the thing is an object, it doesn't tell you what kind of object it is. Details, as always, [in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

`$.type` is a jQuery function that uses `typeof` and various other techniques to try to provide more information. Details, as always, [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.type).

Comment: Thank you T.J. documentation link is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` is native javascript

[$.type()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.type/) is jQuery way to find us a correct required type using suitable approach

> If the argument is either a primitive value or an instance of a
>   standard built-in ECMAScript object, the [[Class]] internal property
>   is used to determine the type.